# Segmentation with piecewise linear regression

Tags: python, data-science, breakpoints, subsequence

I am willing to segment a sequence into `n` subsequences (`n` known) where my points in each subsequence should be similar in a way that a piecewise linear function could fit the points (minimize the distance in each subsequence and the overall sequence).
I have tried the package ruptures with the algo **Binseg** which allows to provide the number of segments and I have also tried numpy/scipy to directly fit **piecewise linear functions**.
Then I realized I need to apply weights to my points, else what I want to achieve doesn't work great. How could I trick either solution, or do you know another solution that could directly take as an argument an **array of weights**?

**Edit for more context:**

- The curve is usually flat, steepening, flattening, concave or convex, or a mix, and consists of at most 40 points (i.e. max sequence is 40)
- There can be 1 or 2 outliers (usually the first point but not necessarily)
- I am aiming at `n` between 4 and 8 (i.e. between 4 and 8 subsequences, defined as a parameter).
- My sequence is at most 40 points, and it's in a loop with ~20 iterations. It must take less than 30sec for the whole loop, so max ~1.5sec per sequence.

Here is an example of the data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Term Dummy':[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32],
    'Shock':[131.759276601612,-5.28111953539055,-5.30412333137685,6.19553924065018,-5.97658803726517,-7.8325986545673,-9.50784210778306,-15.7385664305344,-23.3182508381464,-29.4897840376819,-31.467551725682,-33.4723203935889,-34.6650947285782,-35.7471724234754,-36.4799776375108,-37.3264043303424,-37.4155331344124,-37.8155991350952,-38.7550833588797,-38.3608088160098,-36.7211814243519,-35.7477615422699,-34.1458248652337,-32.8287847811565,-31.4018236645802,-29.9742754473972,-28.6193854123123,-24.90985538625,-21.3217573325541,-18.7350606702909,-16.0799516664911,-16.1549305201347,-16.1433168994669],
    'Weight':[1924,41170,120247,289092,311692,50265,127579,38255,225164,300420,96928,189792,177827,511969,417120,17840,72257,160679,89074,186051,102120,53770,662958,100838,765414,820977,533239,113092,60063,174082,238152,215960,115665]
})
```

`Shock` is the sequence that needs to be reduced to `n` subsequences.
For example, a solution with `n=6` could be (grouping the index/Term dummy):

```
[
[0],
[1,2],
[3],
[4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18],
[19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29],
[30,31,32]
]
```

[image: Shocks and example of segmentation]

The plot below shows 3 curves of `Shock` on the top, and the `Sensitivity` (`Delta` in the plot) and the `Impact`. `Weight` is the absolute value of `Sensitivity`.

[image: Plot of 3 Shock (top), Sensitivity and Impact (bottom)]

Comment: You need to add a lot of context: what your original curve looks like, ideally data to define it, the resolution of your linear approximation, the size of your input, etc.

Comment: What's the application in mind for the piecewise function?  Would you be better suited with linear interpolation or spline interpolation from the actual data?  That would give you the ability to interpolate values at any `x` in a very straightforward way.

Comment: I actually don't need to know the fitting functions, it's just a way to define a cost function to group by subsequences.
The ultimate goal is to do basic aggregation on each subsequence (mean, min, max and maybe a trend: flat, steepening, flattening if the solution integrates linear functions fitting), because it's easier to read 6 rows than 40.

Comment: If it's "reading" you're after, instead of going through the complication of a weighted piecewise fit, you could just produce a moving summary graph for each of the metrics you've mentioned. This would be more accurate, more informative and probably easier to implement.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand what you mean by moving summary graph, is it something like a moving average?
The `Weight` is actually a sensitivity, i.e. a position, I took the absolute value but it's actually very jagged, and the last metric is the `Impact` which I didn't mention here to keep it simple and is `Sensitivity*Shock`. So the `Impact` is also very jagged and can be positive and negative.

Comment: Yes, literally a moving average (and mean differential, etc.), with a fixed-size window that's between 1/4 and 1/8 of the length of your independent variable

Comment: I will give it a try but given the series I have I am not sure it will give information.
PS: I'm adding a picture of the `Sensitivity` (`Delta` in the plot) and the `Impact`.

Comment: It now looks like you want to divide up the `Shock` variable into unequally-sized groups that minimize the differential between them. Is this still in the name of data visualisation? I have no idea what Delta Impact is or how you intend on it affecting your solution

Comment: On the plot there are 33 points (x-axis is `Term` and is equivalent to `Term Dummy`).
On top of the plots, I have a table with the detail on all points, i.e. `Term`, `Shock`, `Sensitivity`, `Impact` (I remind that `Impact` = `Shock`*`Sensitivity`).
The 33 rows are not readable due to the fact that `Sensitivity` is jagged, so yes I would like to divide the `Shock` into subsequences so that I can sum `Sensitivity` and `Impact` within these subsequences and have an easy and good understanding of how to decompose the `Impact`.

Answer (score 0):

This question is all over the place. I'm fairly convinced that it's an x/y problem and you should actually be doing something else; but here is what you originally asked for:

```py
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import minimize, LinearConstraint
import scipy.sparse


def piecewise(y: np.ndarray, n: int) -> np.ndarray:
    """
    :param y: Length-m array to approximate
    :param n: Number of segments
    :return: (n+1) segment bound indices; will always include 0 and m-1
    """
    m = y.size
    x_inferred = np.arange(m)

    def cost(x: np.ndarray) -> float:
        xshort = (0, *x, m-1)
        yshort = np.interp(x=xshort, xp=x_inferred, fp=y)
        y_long = np.interp(x=x_inferred, xp=xshort, fp=yshort)
        error = y_long - y
        return error.dot(error)

    x0 = np.linspace(start=m/n, stop=m*(n - 1)/n, num=n - 1)
    bounds = np.stack((
        np.arange(1, n),
        np.arange(m - n, m - 1),
    ), axis=1)
    increasing = LinearConstraint(
        A=scipy.sparse.eye(n-2, n-1, k=1) - scipy.sparse.eye(n-2, n-1),
        lb=1,
    )
    res = minimize(fun=cost, x0=x0, bounds=bounds, constraints=increasing)
    assert res.success, res.message
    return np.concatenate(((0,), res.x.round().astype(int), (m-1,)))


def test() -> None:
    shock = np.array((
       131.7592766 ,  -5.28111954,  -5.30412333,   6.19553924,
        -5.97658804,  -7.83259865,  -9.50784211, -15.73856643,
       -23.31825084, -29.48978404, -31.46755173, -33.47232039,
       -34.66509473, -35.74717242, -36.47997764, -37.32640433,
       -37.41553313, -37.81559914, -38.75508336, -38.36080882,
       -36.72118142, -35.74776154, -34.14582487, -32.82878478,
       -31.40182366, -29.97427545, -28.61938541, -24.90985539,
       -21.32175733, -18.73506067, -16.07995167, -16.15493052,
       -16.1433169,
    ))

    x = piecewise(y=shock, n=6)
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.set_xticks(x)
    ax.grid(True, color='#CCC')
    ax.scatter(np.arange(shock.size), shock, label='original')
    ax.plot(x, shock[x], label='approx')
    ax.legend()
    plt.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    test()
```

It doesn't do anything clever with regard to global optimization so this may be prone to local solutions, but for your provided data it works well.

[image: fit]

Well-ish. It works better if you use a 2nd-order differential initialization vector (especially for an example like n=8):

```py
from typing import Literal

import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import minimize, LinearConstraint
import scipy.sparse


def piecewise(y: np.ndarray, n: int, init: Literal['2diff', 'dist'] = '2diff') -> np.ndarray:
    """
    :param y: Length-m array to approximate
    :param n: Number of segments
    :param init: Initialization method, either 2nd-order differential or evenly distributed
    :return: (n+1) segment bound indices; will always include 0 and m-1
    """
    m = y.size
    x_inferred = np.arange(m)

    def cost(x: np.ndarray) -> float:
        xshort = (0, *x, m-1)
        yshort = np.interp(x=xshort, xp=x_inferred, fp=y)
        y_long = np.interp(x=x_inferred, xp=xshort, fp=yshort)
        error = y_long - y
        return error.dot(error)

    if init == '2diff':
        diff2 = np.abs(np.diff(np.diff(y)))
        x0 = 1 + np.sort(diff2.argsort()[1-n:])
    else:
        x0 = np.linspace(start=m / n, stop=m * (n - 1) / n, num=n - 1)

    bounds = np.stack((
        np.arange(1, n),
        np.arange(m - n, m - 1),
    ), axis=1)
    increasing = LinearConstraint(
        A=scipy.sparse.eye(n-2, n-1, k=1) - scipy.sparse.eye(n-2, n-1),
        lb=1,
    )
    res = minimize(fun=cost, x0=x0, bounds=bounds, constraints=increasing,)
    assert res.success, res.message
    return np.concatenate(((0,), res.x.round().astype(int), (m-1,)))


def test() -> None:
    shock = np.array((
       131.7592766 ,  -5.28111954,  -5.30412333,   6.19553924,
        -5.97658804,  -7.83259865,  -9.50784211, -15.73856643,
       -23.31825084, -29.48978404, -31.46755173, -33.47232039,
       -34.66509473, -35.74717242, -36.47997764, -37.32640433,
       -37.41553313, -37.81559914, -38.75508336, -38.36080882,
       -36.72118142, -35.74776154, -34.14582487, -32.82878478,
       -31.40182366, -29.97427545, -28.61938541, -24.90985539,
       -21.32175733, -18.73506067, -16.07995167, -16.15493052,
       -16.1433169,
    ))

    xdist = piecewise(y=shock, n=8, init='dist')
    x2diff = piecewise(y=shock, n=8, init='2diff')
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.scatter(np.arange(shock.size), shock, label='original')
    ax.plot(xdist, shock[xdist], label='approx (dist)')
    ax.plot(x2diff, shock[x2diff], label='approx (2diff)')
    ax.legend()
    plt.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    test()
```

[image: 2nd order diff]

Comment: Thanks, I tweaked your code and added a weight to the cost function and it works pretty well. I am now trying to improve it to allow discontinuity (jumps) which will free some constraints. I guess I have to modify the cost function, i.e. tweak the interpolation but have no idea how to proceed. Could you give me so guidance please?
Also, I think it's important to mention, sometimes a point can be an outlier and be a subsequence itself.

Comment: That should go in a new question. For the continuous case, if this answers the original question, consider accepting it and linking to the new question in the comments.